# How to post variable using jQuery to PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to post a variable to PHP page using jQuery and then redirect on that PHP page and echo posted variable.

HTML:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.restauarnt_result').click(function() {
    var RestName = $('#restauarnt_name', this).html();
            $.post('restauarnt.php', { RestName : RestName } );
            window.location = 'restauarnt.php';
});
});
```

After I click on `$('.restauarnt_result')`, automatically redirect to 'restauarnt.php' URL and echo the posted data.

PHP:

```
<?php
   echo $_POST['RestName'];
```

Comment: Why post and redirect at the same time... despite the programing thing, this does not make sense at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of Ajax is to communicate with the server *without* leaving the current page.

Since you want to leave the current page, don't use Ajax.

Create a form, and submit it.

```
var f = jQuery("<form>", { action: 'restauarnt.php', method: 'post' });
f.append(
    jQuery("<input>", { type: "hidden", name: "RestName", value: RestName })
);
jQuery(document.body).append(f);
f.submit();
```

Comment: I agree with this answer, jquery to form variable (hidden), very simple solution.

Comment: No, that's as simple as it gets.

Answer (score 1):

There's not much point in using ajax if you're immediately going to redirect

```
<form method="post" action="restauarnt.php">
<input name="RestName"/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

restauarnt.php

```
<? 
echo $_POST['RestName'];
```

Comment: This doesn't handle the content of the JS variable `RestName`.

Answer (score 0):

On the PHP side use session:

```
<?php
session_start();
// store session data
$_SESSION['RestName']= "RestName";
?>
```

After reload, this value will be in the new session variable.

Answer (score 0):

You should redirect after the call is completed. So try this-

```
$.post('restauarnt.php', { RestName : RestName }, function(data){
   // here the call is completed
   console.log(data); // this will print the values echo by the php
   window.location = 'restauarnt.php';
} );
```

Comment: sir,  error : Undefined index: RestName in C:\wamp\www\restauarnt.php on line 6

Comment: `console.log(RestName)` before calling the `ajax.post`